Locking a Fully Managed Company Owned Mobile Device
I want to lock a mobile device using the Google Management API. After I lock the device, the user should not be able to unlock it. The device will display only one screen until the IT admin unlocks it. How can I achieve this using the Google Management API?
I also don't know what permissions I need to add to the policy to achieve this.
I have tried to lock the device using the API's Lost Mode, but the user can unlock the device if they know the passcode. This is not the solution I wanted. Only admin can lock and unlock the device
can you guy's tell me how can i do this
